# How to implement inspect and highlight functionality from Axe DevTools into my custom DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, accessibility, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am using the Axe accessibility library to generate accessibility reports for a web application. The reports include code selectors for each accessibility issue, which I would like to use to navigate to the relevant code and highlight the corresponding html in element panel from my custom DevTools extension.

I would like to implement a functionality similar to the "Inspect" and "Highlight" buttons in Axe DevTools, which allows users to navigate to the corresponding element in the DevTools Elements panel and highlight code in page.

Some specific questions I have are:

- How can I use the code css selector to navigate to the relevant code and highlight the corresponding html in elements panel from my custom DevTools extension?
- What code from Axe DevTools do I need to extract to implement the highlight functionality?
- Are there any existing libraries or tools that can help me with this implementation?
- Are there any known issues or pitfalls I should be aware of when implementing these functionalities?
- Here is the image have look
  [axe devtools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Btv1.png) ,
  [highlight image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XTU8.png)

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

file stucture: [my devtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y6Rc.png)

I have looked for the Axe DevTools source code but I didn't get much info how to bring the relevant code for these functionalities. Can anyone provide guidance on how to implement this, or point me to relevant resources?
I've looked into the documentation for Axe DevTools and the Chrome DevTools protocol, but I'm still unsure how to proceed.